# How to resolve InstancePerLifetimeScope component from within SingleInstace component via Func?

Tags: autofac

The idea is just simple and works in the other containers, not limited with .Net:
Singleton component being referenced from within request context references transient component which in turn references request-scoped component (some UnitOfWork).

I expected that Autofac would resolve the same scoped component in both cases:
- when I request it directly from request scope
- when I request it by invoking Func<>
Unfortunately the reality is quite a bit different - Autofac sticks SingleInstance component to the root scope and resolves InstancePerLifetimeScope component on 
the root component introducing memory leak (!!!) as UnitOfWork is disposable and becomes tracked by root scope (attempt to use matching web request scope would just fail finding request scope which is yet more misleading).

Now I'm wondering whether such behavior is by design or just a bug? If it is by design I'm not sure what are the use cases and why it differs from the other containers.

The example is as follows (including working SimpleInjector case):

```
namespace AutofacTest
{
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

using Autofac;

using NUnit.Framework;

using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Lifestyles;

public class SingletonComponent
{
    public Func<TransientComponent> Transient { get; }

    public Func<ScopedComponent> Scoped { get; }

    public SingletonComponent(Func<TransientComponent> transient, Func<ScopedComponent> scoped)
    {
        Transient = transient;
        Scoped = scoped;
    }
}

public class ScopedComponent : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}

public class TransientComponent
{
    public ScopedComponent Scoped { get; }

    public TransientComponent(ScopedComponent scopedComponent)
    {
        this.Scoped = scopedComponent;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AutofacTest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            SimpleInjectorTest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

   private static void AutofacTest()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ScopedComponent>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<SingletonComponent>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<TransientComponent>();

        var container = builder.Build();

        var outerSingleton = container.Resolve<SingletonComponent>();

        using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var singleton = scope.Resolve<SingletonComponent>();
            Assert.That(outerSingleton, Is.SameAs(singleton));

            var transient = scope.Resolve<TransientComponent>();
            var scoped = scope.Resolve<ScopedComponent>();

            Assert.That(singleton.Transient(), Is.Not.SameAs(transient));
            // this fails
            Assert.That(singleton.Transient().Scoped, Is.SameAs(scoped));
            Assert.That(transient.Scoped, Is.SameAs(scoped));

            Assert.That(singleton.Scoped(), Is.SameAs(scoped)); // this fails
            Assert.That(singleton.Transient(), Is.Not.SameAs(transient));
        }
    }

    private static void SimpleInjectorTest()
    {
        var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
        container.Options.AllowResolvingFuncFactories();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        container.Register<ScopedComponent>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<SingletonComponent>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        container.Register<TransientComponent>(Lifestyle.Transient);
        container.Verify();

        var outerSingleton = container.GetInstance<SingletonComponent>();

        using (var scope = AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
        {
            var singleton = container.GetInstance<SingletonComponent>();
            Assert.That(outerSingleton, Is.SameAs(singleton));

            var transient = container.GetInstance<TransientComponent>();
            var scoped = container.GetInstance<ScopedComponent>();

            Assert.That(singleton.Transient(), Is.Not.SameAs(transient));
            Assert.That(singleton.Transient().Scoped, Is.SameAs(scoped));
            Assert.That(transient.Scoped, Is.SameAs(scoped));

            Assert.That(singleton.Scoped(), Is.SameAs(scoped));
            Assert.That(singleton.Transient(), Is.Not.SameAs(transient));
        }
    }
}

public static class SimpleInjectorExtensions
{
    public static void AllowResolvingFuncFactories(this ContainerOptions options)
    {
        options.Container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) =>
            {
                var type = e.UnregisteredServiceType;

                if (!type.IsGenericType || type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Func<>))
                {
                    return;
                }

                Type serviceType = type.GetGenericArguments().First();

                InstanceProducer registration = options.Container.GetRegistration(serviceType, true);

                Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);

                var factoryDelegate = Expression.Lambda(funcType, registration.BuildExpression()).Compile();

                e.Register(Expression.Constant(factoryDelegate));
            };
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version what you're seeing is not a bug, you're just misunderstanding some of the finer points of lifetime scopes and captive dependencies.

First, a couple of background references from the Autofac docs:

- [Controlling Scope and Lifetime](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/index.html) explains a lot about how lifetime scopes and that hierarchy works.
- [Captive Dependencies](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html) talks about why you don't generally shouldn't take an instance-per-lifetime or instance-per-dependency scoped item into a singleton.
- [Disposal](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) talks about how Autofac auto-disposes `IDisposable` items and how you can opt out of that.
- [Implicit Relationship Types](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html) describes the `Owned<T>` relationship type used as part of the `IDisposable` opt-out.

Some big key takeaways from these docs that directly affect your situation:

- **Autofac tracks `IDisposable` components so they can be automatically disposed along with the lifetime scope.** That means it will *hold references to any resolved `IDisposable` objects* until the parent lifetime scope is resolved.
- **You can opt out of `IDisposable` tracking** either by registering the component as `ExternallyOwned` *or* by using `Owned<T>` in the constructor parameter being injected. (Instead of taking in an `IDependency` take in an `Owned<IDependency>`.)
- **Singletons live in the root lifetime scope.** That means any time you resolve a singleton it will be resolved from the root lifetime scope. If it is `IDisposable` it will be tracked in the root lifetime scope and not released until that root scope - the container itself - is disposed.
- **The `Func<T>` dependency relationship is tied to the same lifetime scope as the object in which it's injected.** If you have a singleton, that means the `Func<T>` will resolve things from the same lifetime scope as the singleton - the root lifetime scope. If you have something that's instance-per-dependency, the `Func<T>` will be attached to whatever scope the owning component is in.

Knowing that, you can see why your singleton, which takes in a `Func<T>`, keeps trying to resolve these things from the root lifetime scope. You can also see why you're seeing a memory leak situation - you haven't opted out of the disposal tracking for the things that are being resolved by that `Func<T>`.

So the question is, how do you fix it?

**Option 1: Redesign**

Generally speaking, it would be better to invert the relationship between the singleton and the thing you have to resolve via `Func<T>`; or stop using a singleton altogether and let that be a smaller lifetime scope.

For example, say you have some `IDatabase` service that needs an `IPerformTransaction` to get things done. The database connection is expensive to spin up, so you might make that a singleton. You might then have something like this:

```
public class DatabaseThing : IDatabase
{
  public DatabaseThing(Func<IPerformTransaction> factory) { ... }
  public void DoWork()
  {
    var transaction = this.factory();
    transaction.DoSomethingWithData(this.Data);
  }
}
```

So, like, the thing that's *expensive* to spin up uses a `Func<T>` to generate the cheap thing on the fly and work with it.

Inverting that relationship would look like this:

```
public PerformsTransaction : IPerformTransaction
{
  public PerformsTransaction(IDatabase database) { ... }
  public void DoSomethingWithData()
  {
    this.DoSomething(this.Database.Data);
  }
}
```

The idea is that you'd resolve the transaction thing and it'd take the singleton in as a dependency. The cheaper item could easily be disposed along with child lifetime scopes (i.e., per request) but the singleton would remain.

It'd be better to redesign if you can because even with the other options you'll have a rough time getting "instance per request" sorts of things into a singleton. (And that's a bad idea anyway from both a captive dependency and threading standpoint.)

**Option 2: Abandon Singleton**

If you can't redesign, a good second choice would be to make the lifetime of the singleton... not be a singleton. Let it be instance-per-scope or instance-per-dependency and stop using `Func<T>`. Let everything get resolved from a child lifetime scope and be disposed when the scope is disposed.

I recognize that's not always possible for a variety of reasons. But if it *is* possible, that's another way to escape the problem.

**Option 3: Use `ExternallyOwned`**

If you can't redesign, you could register the disposable items consumed by the singleton as `ExternallyOwned`.

```
builder.RegisterType<ThingConsumedBySingleton>()
       .As<IConsumedBySingleton>()
       .ExternallyOwned();
```

Doing that will tell Autofac to not track the disposable. You won't have the memory leak. You *will* be responsible for disposing the resolved objects yourself. You will also still be getting them from the root lifetime scope since the singleton is getting a `Func<T>` injected.

```
public void MethodInsideSingleton()
{
  using(var thing = this.ThingFactory())
  {
    // Do the work you need to and dispose of the
    // resolved item yourself when done.
  }
}
```

**Option 4: `Owned<T>`**

If you don't want to *always* manually dispose of the service you're consuming - you only want to deal with that inside the singleton - you could register it as normal but consume a `Func<Owned<T>>`. Then the singleton will resolve things as expected but *the container won't track it for disposal*.

```
public void MethodInsideSingleton()
{
  using(var ownedThing = this.ThingFactory())
  {
    var thing = ownedThing.Value;
    // Do the work you need to and dispose of the
    // resolved item yourself when done.
  }
}
```

Comment: Travis Illig, thank you for your thorough answer. I tend to think that I would opt to avoid captive dependencies completely. Do you consider adding a setting to make Autofac prohibit creating captive dependencies and thus slipping instances into the root scope?